# Counting prime numbers

Tags: java, primes

I have been working on a Euler problem for some time. My program displays prime numbers but I would like to see which number it is, in order.

```
public class Euler7 {
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        boolean prime = true;

        for(int count = 2; count <= 1000; count++){
            for(int count1 = 2; count1 <= Math.sqrt(count); count1++) {
                prime = true;
                if(count%count1==0) {
                    prime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(prime == true) {           
                System.out.println(count);
            }   
        }                 
    }
}
```

Comment: rename `count` as `number`; add new counter named `count` and increment it only when a prime is about to be printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution, `2` is the first prime number.

```
public class Euler7 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean prime;
        int cnt = 0;

        for(int count = 2; count <= 1000; count++){
            prime = true;
            for(int count1 = 2; count1 <= Math.sqrt(count); count1++) {
                if(count%count1==0) {
                    prime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(prime){
                cnt++;
                System.out.println(cnt + "th prime number is " + count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could refactor it little bit,for instance you could add each prime to list, and then in your inner loop you could try to divide number only by prime numbers